# Add Customize action ng2-smart-table but no action added

Tags: angular, smart-table, ng2-smart-table

I'm trying create customize action but something went wrong, the code not given me custom action button

My settings, I added custom button inside **actions**:

```
settings = {
actions: {
  edit: false,
  custom: [
    { 
      name: 'routeToAPage', 
      title: `<i class="ion-person" title="Xem thông tin người nhận Giftcode"></i>` 
    }
  ],
},
add: {
  addButtonContent: '<i class="ion-ios-plus-outline"></i>',
  createButtonContent: '<i class="ion-checkmark"></i>',
  cancelButtonContent: '<i class="ion-close"></i>',
  confirmCreate: true
},
columns: {
  stt: {
    title: 'STT',
    editable: false,
  },
},
pager : {
    display : true,
    perPage: 10
}
};
```

My Html code:

```
      <ba-card class="smart-table-container">
          <ng2-smart-table 
          [settings]="settings" 
          [source]="source" 
          (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"
          (custom)="onCustom($event)"
          ></ng2-smart-table>
      </ba-card>
```

What's my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i have tried this. Do go through my code 
      source: LocalDataSource;

```
  settings = {
   columns: {
  Status: {
    title: 'Status'
    , class: 'align-centerr'
  },
  FullName: {
    title: 'Full Name'
  },
  JobTitle: {
    title: 'Job Title'
  },
  Department: {
    title: 'Department'
  },
  EmailAddress: {
    title: 'Email Address'
  },
  MobilePhone: {
    title: 'Mobile No'
  },


},
actions: {
  edit: false,
  custom: [{ name: 'Edit', title: `<i  class="fa fa-edit"></i>` },
    { name: 'Activate', title: `<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>` },
    { name: 'Deactivate', title: `<i  class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i>` }
  ],

},


delete: {
  deleteButtonContent: '',
  confirmDelete: true
},
add: null,
defaultStyle: false
  ,
    rowClassFunction: (row) => {
    if (row.data.Status === 'Inactive')
   {
         return 'success-table';
   } else if (row.data.Status === 'Active') {
    return 'warning-table';

  }
}
```